# Smarter this shorthand

Tags: javascript, shorthand

I've got two situations where I'm declaring `var that = this` and I'm wondering if there is a smarter way of handling it with a native function like `call()` or `apply()` so I don't have to create an anonymous function?

```
var that = this;
this.listenTo( foo, 'event', function() {
    that.trigger( 'change' );
});

var that = this;
this.listenTo( foo, 'event', function( bar ) {
    that.add( bar );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Function#bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

So something like this:

```
this.listenTo( foo, 'event', function() {
    this.trigger( 'change' );
}.bind(this));

this.listenTo( foo, 'event', function( bar ) {
    this.add( bar );
}.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested (especialy I think to much binds and this), but how about like this:

```
this.triggerFn = function(ev) {
    return function() {
        this.trigger(ev);
    }.bind(this);
}.bind(this);

this.addFn = function() {
    return function(bar) {
        this.add(bar);
    }.bind(this);
}.bind(this);

this.listenTo( foo, 'event', this.triggerFn('change'));

this.listenTo( foo, 'event', this.addFn( bar ));
```

For bind polyfill see [that](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/).